# Rewrite this foreach yield to a linq yield?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lazy-loading, yield

Say I have the following code (context narrowed down as to keep the question scope limited)

```
public static IEnumerable<Color> GetThemColors(){
    var ids = GetThePrimaryIds();
    foreach (int id in ids){
        yield return GetColorById(id);
    }
    ids = GetTheOtherIds();
    foreach (int id in ids){
        yield return GetOtherColorsById(id);
    }
}
```

I would like to rewrite them to something like this (which off course doesn't compile

```
public static IEnumerable<Color> GetThemColors(){
    GetThePrimaryIds().Select(id=>yield return GetColorById(id));
    GetTheOtherIds().Select(id=>yield return GetOtherColorsById(id));       
}
```

The key point being that in my first snippet I have two foreach enumerators yielding, which I don't know how to do in linq without loosing my lazy-loading features.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want `Concat`:

```
return GetThePrimaryIds().Select(id => GetColorById(id)).Concat(
    GetTheOtherIds().Select(id => GetOtherColorsById(id)));
```

Also note that you don't need `yield return` in lambdas.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize the concat was lazy

Comment: As far as I know all the methods on Enumerable that return an IEnumerable are lazy.

Comment: True, but I assumed for some reason Concat would return a IList

Comment: It should be noted that the call to `GetTheOtherIds()` is _not_ lazy, i.e. it will first call `GetThePrimaryIds()`, then call `GetTheOtherIds()`, then call `Concat()`. However, if the methods themselves are lazy, then it's not a problem.

Comment: @borisCallens: if that were the case, it would have been declared as returning `IList` or `ICollection`